# Creating many-to-many relationship on self object class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I currently have a problem for a project where I need to create many-to-many relationships on the same class. I have a class named "Company" where I have some attributes. The relationship I want to create is:

One or more than one company can have one or more competitor. Where a competitor is in fact a company.

I already tried many solutions found on Internet but it seems not to be a good idea to represent the entity relationship I want to have and an easy way to use it in my model.

Here is my class:

```cs
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CommercialName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I tried to add in this class the following line:

```cs
public ICollection<Company> Concurrents { get; set; }
```

But EF code first add a new column "company_id" in my "company" table.
What's the best way to add a list of concurrent in this class that is represented by a new table in my DB with 2 column representing the "Id" of company objects?